# When using PowerCLI Invoke-VMScript against RHEL 6, the ifconfig and ping commands do not provide a response, why?

Tags: linux, powershell, powercli, rhel6

I'm currently trying to generate a PowerCLI script that will configure the network adapters for a newly provisioned RHEL 6 VM. I've accomplished this with Windows 2012 R2, but for RHEL 6 I've noticed that some of the commands do not behave correctly when executed with Invoke-VMscript.

Executing `ifconfig` or `ping -c 2 localhost` locally on the VM as root performs as expected but when executing the command via Invoke-VMscript, the ScriptOutput block is blank. Running other commands such as `pwd`, `ls`, and `cat /somefile` work as expected. Another clue is that the `ll` command returns "bash: ll: command not found" while it works fine on the console.

I found the following VMware community article describing the same situation but it was not answered: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/467281

The exact command I'm using is

```
    Invoke-VMscript -ScriptText "ifconfig" -VM $VM1 -GuestCredential $cred
```

I've tried using a non-root account as the guest credential but due to the escalation setup in use I get the following error: "A specfified parameter was not correct"

Comment: Did you install VMtools or Open VM tools?

Comment: @user3520245 Yes, the VMware tools installer was run. Before running the installer, the command fails with a timeout error.

Comment: Sounds like tools is not install properly? Surprised you get any results. OpenVM tools is better for Linux, try getting that installed.